# Why does freeing TObjectList also deletes controls?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, tobjectlist

I use TObjectList to process specific list of labels. But when I do the recommended .Free in Try Final, it also deletes the controls from the list.

Simple example with 3 labels:

```
Procedure GetHeaderLabels(var aList:TObjectList<TLabel>);
begin
  aList.Add(Form1.lblHeaderCars);
  aList.Add(Form1.lblHeaderBrands);
  aList.Add(Form1.lblHeaderModels);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var vHeaderLabelsList:TObjectList<TLabel>;
begin
  vHeaderLabelsList:=TObjectList<TLabel>.Create;
  try
     GetHeaderLabels(vHeaderLabelsList);
      {... process Header Labels }
  finally
    vHeaderLabelsList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In this case when I execute this code I end up with missing label controls - they are deleted from the form and in debug I see that controls are nil.

Am I not supposed to .Free TObjectList? How can I Free TObjectlist and still keep the controls?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TObjectList` has an `OwnsObjects` property, which by default is `True`. If you don't change that at some point before you free it, it will free the objects it contains. If you don't want that, then set `OwnsObjects` to `False`.

```
vHeaderLabelsList := TObjectList<TLabel>.Create(False);
```

If you don't need the objects owned (cleaned up) by the TObjectList, it would be better to simply use TList instead:

```
vHeaderLabelsList := TList<TLabel>.Create;
```

Comment: No, I only need a list of them to avoid copying same code for each label.

Answer (score 9):

You stumbled on the difference between [`TObjectList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList) and [`TList<TObject>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList).

An `TObjectList` 'owns' the objects in the list, which means that by default it will destroy all the objects contained therein when an object is removed from the list or when the list itself is destroyed.
If you don't want that to happen either use a `TList<TObject>` or set the [`OwnsObjects`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList.OwnsObjects) to false before adding items to the list.
This is typically done in the constructor, but you can set it afterwards as well.

All this is clearly indicated in the documentation.

> If the entry is owned, when the entry object is removed from the list, the entry object is freed.
>
> The OwnsObjects property gets or sets the object ownership.

You should really check out: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com when something unexpected happens before rushing to SO :-).

Comment: Note that there is also a non-Generic version of `TObjectList` that also has an `OwnsObjects` property.  And `TStringList` also has an `OwnsObjects` property for the entries in its `Objects[]` property.

Comment: I read the documentation but only to see that ot should do the job. Obviously I shoud read further.

Comment: Worth noting however is that the documentation for TObjectList<T> identifies this *capability* but does not say whether it is enabled by default only that a ctor parameter turns it on or off.  As written, the documentation gives no reason to think that this is the *default* behaviour (unless you specifically and separately check the *Create* constructor reference and discover that the mentioned parameter is TRUE, if not specified).  By contrast, the **Contnrs.TObjectList** documentation *is* clear that this is the default behaviour.  "RTFM" fails when the FM is FU.  :)